# extern keyword with multiple files

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ from `Programming Principles and Practices using C++ by Bjarne Stroustrup`. I am facing trouble with `foo` variable during compiling. Read many other links on `extern` keyword but still couldn't figure out the problem.

```
//ch8d1_my.h

extern int foo;
void print_foo();
void print(int);

//ch8d1_my.cpp
#include "ch8d1_my.h"
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

void print_foo()
{
  cout << "foo = " << foo << '\n';
}

void print(int i)
{ 
  cout << "i = " << i << '\n';
}


//ch8d1_use.cpp

#include "ch8d1_my.h"

int main()
{ 
 int foo = 7;
  print_foo();
  print(99);
 return 0;
}

Error: ch8d1_use.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
ch8d1_use.cpp:5:6: warning: unused variable ‘foo’ [-Wunused-variable]
  int foo = 7;
      ^
/tmp/ccoVkK6R.o: In function `print_foo()':
ch8d1_my.cpp:(.text+0xb): undefined reference to `foo'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ## include "ch8d1_my.h"             //this is wrong. should be at the start of file
>
> ## include "std_lib_facilities.h"  //this is wrong. should be at the start of

```
#include "ch8d1_my.h"
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

extern int foo;
void print_foo();
void print(int);

//ch8d1_my.cpp
int foo = 7;       //You need to declare extern as global variable
   
void print_foo()
{
  cout << "foo = " << foo << '\n';
}

void print(int i)
{ 
  cout << "i = " << i << '\n';
}
```

//ch8d1_use.cpp

```
#include "ch8d1_my.h"

int main()
{ 
  print_foo();
  print(99);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are three files ch8d1_my.h, ch8d1_my.cpp and ch8d1_use.cpp . All declarations have been done in ch8d1_my.h header file.